# Rails 3 Asset Pipeline - Don't compress certain javascript files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

My asset precompilation fails due to one javascript file (ckeditor.js) that is already compressed and uglifier can't parse it.

Since there is no real point of compressing it twice I would like to make uglifier ignore that certain file (all the others work fine).

One solution I can think off the top of my head is to simply move it into /public and reference it from there, but that would also mean I miss out on the gzip compression and the fingerprinting the precompilation does for me.

My config in case you wonder:

```
  # Asset precompilation                                                                                                                                                                                 
  config.assets.digest = true                                                                                                                                                                            
  config.assets.compress = true                                                                                                                                                                          
  config.assets.compile = false                                                                                                                                                                          
  config.assets.precompile += %w{apple.css libs/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js admin/ckeditor.js}                                                                       
  config.assets.css_compressor = :yui
```

I'm using Rails 3.2

Comment: I would add a .min to all the files that have already been compressed and have the precompile skip it with a regex rule to ignore all the '.min.js' files. Not sure if this would actually work better than moving to /public.

Comment: Well that doesn't really solve the issue. I'd love to have them compiled into the application.js and also fingerprinted etc.. Ignoring them is pretty much the same as moving them to /public

Answer (score -2):

Just put it uncompressed and have uglifier do the job for all files

Comment: If I had the uncompressed build of that file things would be a lot simpler :)